# Função JavaScript não funciona depois do else if

Tags: javascript, html, css, aplicação-web, bootstrap

Para contextualizar: O código é uma página com algumas `RadioBox` onde cada uma deve ter uma função e cada uma mostrar elementos HTML diferentes dependendo da necessidade (isso funcionou perfeitamente). O problema é que na função `ready()` o código não funciona depois do `else` (linha 6). (Eu testei só a primeira parte do if separado e também só a parte depois do else e ambas funcionaram como deveriam, o problema é quando estão como no código).

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/bootswatch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
        <link href="icomoon/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    </head>

    <body onload="rFunction()">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="imgs/jslogo.png" class="img100"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="ex1.html">Exercício 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Exercício 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Escolha uma opção:</legend>
                    <div class="form-group" id="form01">
                        <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Opções:</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="sqrt" checked="true" type="radio" onchange="rFunction()">
                                    Calcular a raiz quadrada de um número.
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="bigger" type="radio" onchange="rFunction2()">
                                    Informar dois números e mostrar o maior número.
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="exp" type="radio" onchange="rFunction3()">
                                    Informar a base e o expoente e elevar ao expoente informado.
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="sum" type="radio" onchange="rFunction4()">
                                    Informar dois números e mostrar o resultado da soma.
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios5" value="upcase" type="radio" onchange="rFunction5()">
                                    Informar uma frase em letras minúsculas e mostrar a frase em letras maiúsculas.
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ready()">Pronto!</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form><br>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
function rFunction(){
    if($("#optionsRadios1").value = true){
        if($(".crClass")){
            $("div").remove(".crClass");
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'crClass';
        div.id = 'option1';
        var lbl = document.createElement('label');
        lbl.className = 'col-xs-2 control-label';
        div.appendChild(lbl);
        var txt = document.createTextNode("Digite um número:");
        lbl.appendChild(txt);

        var txtA = document.createElement('input');
        txtA.setAttribute("type","number");
        txtA.className = 'col-xs-2';
        txtA.id = 'txtA1';
        div.appendChild(txtA);
        document.getElementById('form01').appendChild(div);        
    }
}

function rFunction2(){
    if($("#optionsRadios2").value = true){
        if($(".crClass")){
            $("div").remove(".crClass");
        }

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'crClass';
        div.id = 'option2';
        var lbl = document.createElement('label');
        lbl.className = 'col-xs-2 control-label';
        div.appendChild(lbl);
        var txt = document.createTextNode("Digite um número:");
        lbl.appendChild(txt);

        var txtA = document.createElement('input');
        txtA.setAttribute("type","number");
        txtA.className = 'col-xs-2';
        txtA.id = 'txtA2';
        div.appendChild(txtA);
        document.getElementById('form01').appendChild(div);

        var div0 = document.createElement('div');
        div0.className = 'crClass';
        div0.id = 'option3';
        var lbl0 = document.createElement('label');
        lbl0.className = 'col-xs-2 control-label';
        div0.appendChild(lbl0);
        var txt0 = document.createTextNode("Digite outro número:");
        lbl0.appendChild(txt0);

        var txtA0 = document.createElement('input');
        txtA0.setAttribute("type","number");
        txtA0.className = 'col-xs-2';
        txtA0.id = 'txtA3';
        div0.appendChild(txtA0);
        document.getElementById('form01').appendChild(div0);
    }
}

function ready(){
    if($("#option1")){
        var number = document.getElementById("txtA1").value;
        var result = Math.sqrt(number);
        alert('Resultado: ' + result);
    } else if($("#option2") && $("#option3")){
        var n1 = document.getElementById("txtA2").value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("txtA3").value;
        if(n1>n2){
            alert(n1);
        } else if(n2>n1){
            alert(n2);
        } else{
            alert("Igual");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tem como detalhar melhor o problema? Não deu para entender exatamente qual é. O que deveria ser executado e o que está sendo executado de fato?

Comment: @Heitor , realmente não esta claro qual é o comportamento que você esta esperando.

Comment: Na função ready() o que eu esperava era que depois do else ela  executasse aquele bloco, disparando um alerta para situação apontada (n1>n2, n2>n1...). O que está acontecendo é que ela só executa a primeira parte (if($("#option1"))..., alertando o resultado desse primeiro bloco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mude sua função ready() para como se segue, pois ao usar $("#option1") sempre vai entrar no primeiro if, ele está retornando objetos mesmo após o remove.

```
function ready(){
    if(document.getElementById('option1')){
        var number = document.getElementById("txtA1").value;
        var result = Math.sqrt(number);
        alert('Resultado: ' + result);
    } else if(document.getElementById('option2') && document.getElementById('option3')){
        var n1 = document.getElementById("txtA2").value;
        var n2 = document.getElementById("txtA3").value;
        if(n1>n2){
            alert(n1);
        } else if(n2>n1){
            alert(n2);
        } else{
            alert("Igual");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: funcionou certinho agora, obrigado!! tu podes me dizer porque isso acontece quando se usa a sintaxe que eu havia usado e porque corrige com essa, por favor?

Comment: Porque o if($("#option1")) sempre vai retornar true, mesmo quando o item já não existe mais, o $("#option1") retorna um objeto, você pode testar fazendo um alert com $("#option1") ou qualquer id que não exista $("#opt") por exemplo e nunca vai ser falso, vai retornar um objeto, por isso ao pegar por id com javascript e não jquery funciona, pois não ocorre isso com javascript.